# add_action('delete_category') Event - get the name of the deleted category

Tags: php, wordpress, action, categories

I want to trigger an event when a category is added or deleted.

So I think the add_action i look for are these

```
create_category
delete_category
```

(got them from here  [source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference))

In the Event I want to have a function where the ID and the name of the category is sent to me.

At the moment I am struggling with the delete operation. The Id seems to delivered properly. The category "name" unfortunately not.

My guess is at the moment that the database no longer contains the name of the category. Probably because the delete_category is invoked after the job is already done. Therefore "get_cat_name()" might not work. Unfortunately I could not find some kind of "pre_delte_category" action.

Here are the functions i placed as hooks in my functions.php of my theme:

```php
function event_by_add_cat($category_id){
   $name = get_cat_name($category_id);
    send_me_mail_add($name, $category_id);
}
add_action('create_category', 'event_by_add_cat');

function event_by_del_cat($category_id){
    $name = get_cat_name($category_id);  // is name already to far gone?
    send_me_mail_del($name, category_id);
    return;
}
add_action('delete_category', 'event_by_del_cat');
```

The function `send_me_mail_add(name, id)` does work.

It seems that the function is send_me_mail_del(name, id); is not called correct. Unfortunately WP shows me no Errors.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to get the name that way, as you guessed, the name is already deleted and there is no 'pre' hook.

You could work arround that by hooking a function to the creation of categories, that adds the name to a different table in the database, togehter with the ID.

And then, if the category gets deleted, you can look the name up there and then also delete it afterwards.